Animate gradient brush in .NET MAUI?
So, I'm trying to create a border with animated gradient colors and archive a rgb effect. Somehow the color is just static(like in the picture below), it doesn't animate at all and this is where i need some help. The docs are limited and literally don't explain anything about this, like WPF docs would:
Static color gradient
The simple code i used:
private LinearGradientBrush gradientBrush;
private Border brd;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush
    {
        StartPoint = new Point(0, 0),
        EndPoint = new Point(1, 0),
        GradientStops = new GradientStopCollection
        {
            new GradientStop { Color = Colors.Red, Offset = 0.0f },
            new GradientStop { Color = Colors.Green, Offset = 0.5f },
            new GradientStop { Color = Colors.Blue, Offset = 1.0f }
        }
    };

    brd = new Border
    {
        StrokeThickness = 5,
        BackgroundColor = Colors.White,
        Stroke = gradientBrush,
        Padding = 10,
        Content = new Label
        {
            Text = "Hello",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            TextColor = Colors.Black,
        }
    };

    Content = new Grid
    {
        Children = { brd }
    };


}

private async void AnimateGradient()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(
            AnimateColor(gradientBrush.GradientStops[0], Colors.Red, Colors.Purple, 2000),
            AnimateColor(gradientBrush.GradientStops[1], Colors.Green, Colors.Yellow, 2000),
            AnimateColor(gradientBrush.GradientStops[2], Colors.Blue, Colors.Cyan, 2000)
        );

        await Task.WhenAll(
            AnimateColor(gradientBrush.GradientStops[0], Colors.Purple, Colors.Red, 2000),
            AnimateColor(gradientBrush.GradientStops[1], Colors.Yellow, Colors.Green, 2000),
            AnimateColor(gradientBrush.GradientStops[2], Colors.Cyan, Colors.Blue, 2000)
        );
    }
}

private Task AnimateColor(GradientStop gradientStop, Color fromColor, Color toColor, uint duration)
{
    var animation = new Animation(v =>
    {
        gradientStop.Color = new Color(
            (float)(fromColor.Red + v * (toColor.Red - fromColor.Red)),
            (float)(fromColor.Green + v * (toColor.Green - fromColor.Green)),
            (float)(fromColor.Blue + v * (toColor.Blue - fromColor.Blue)),
            (float)(fromColor.Alpha + v * (toColor.Alpha - fromColor.Alpha))
        );
        InvalidateMeasure();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(brd));

    });

    animation.Commit(this, gradientStop.GetHashCode().ToString(), length: duration, easing: Easing.Linear);
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(gradientBrush));
    return Task.Delay((int)duration);
}

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        AnimateGradient();
    }

Debugged and tested, code does execute.

What .NET version and platform do you use?

.Net 8, Maui 8.0.70, Windows

I can reproduce the question based on your code. You may raise an issue on GitHub. But if you apply animated gradient color on Border.Background instead of Border.Stroke, it does work.
So, as a workaround you may nest a smaller Border(or other container) in the outer Border. Set the Background of the inner Border to white and the Background of the outer Border to the animated gradient Brush,
        brd = new Border
        {
            Background = gradientBrush,
            Padding = 10,
            Content = new Border
            {
                Margin = 5,
                StrokeThickness = 0,
                BackgroundColor= Colors.White,
                Content = new Label
                {
                    Text = "Hello",
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    TextColor = Colors.Black,
                }
            }              
        };


For creating simple animations, I sometimes create a dummy ContentView and set

TranslationX = 0
TranslationY = 0
use TranslateTo(some_value, 0, duration) to animate "TranslationX"
I use PropertyChanged events to drive animations based on changes to TranslationX

To achieve the effect we want, I think it's sufficient to update StartPoint, EndPoint of your LinearGradientBrush:
private LinearGradientBrush gradientBrush;
private Border brd;
private ContentView animation = new ContentView();

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush
    {
        StartPoint = new Point(0, 0),
        EndPoint = new Point(1, 1),
        GradientStops = new GradientStopCollection
        {
            new GradientStop { Color = Colors.Red, Offset = 0.0f },
            new GradientStop { Color = Colors.Green, Offset = 0.5f },
            new GradientStop { Color = Colors.Blue, Offset = 1.0f }
        }
    };

    brd = new Border
    {
        StrokeThickness = 250,
        BackgroundColor = Colors.White,
        Stroke = gradientBrush,
        Padding = 10,
        Content = new Label
        {
            Text = "Hello",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            TextColor = Colors.Black,
        }
    };

    Content = new Grid
    {
        Children = { brd }
    };

    animation.TranslationX = 0;
    animation.TranslationY = 0;
    animation.TranslateTo(2 * Math.PI * 10, 0, 2000 * 10);
    animation.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        double x = Math.Cos(animation.TranslationX);
        double y = Math.Sin(animation.TranslationX);
        gradientBrush.StartPoint = new Point(-x * 0.5 + 0.5, -y * 0.5 + 0.5);
        gradientBrush.EndPoint = new Point(x * 0.5 + 0.5, y * 0.5 + 0.5);
    };
}


Hmm.. yeah that would be a good workaround. Mind also explaing why the colors don't work?
